# Lenovo T500 - Can't update my Intel driver (driver won't install)

Tags: drivers, thinkpad, vga

Back then I opened a topic about updating switchable driver. When you can use both cards. This is kinda buggy, makes explorer crash, doesn't worth it.

I switched to static cards so to say. For a while I've been using only the ATI card. Now I'll travel a lot so I need the Intel because it eats less.

**However**, I can't update the driver. It's an Intel MHD4500. Tried both Intel's and Lenovo's driver download. Even the ATI driver, NO use.

Here are the infos about it:
- Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family
- Driver provider: ATI Technologies Inc.
- Driver version: 8.641.1.1000
- Driver Data: 8/24/2009
(Its oooold)

Well... ATI..but why? This driver got installed by Windows when I switched the VGA. But in the BIOS I used the setting "NO AUTODETECT" and "INTEGRATED GRAPHICS"... so basically Intel driver *should* work.

Any idea, help, comment, *anything* is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

GPU-Z info.. I've got TWO cards there:
First:
GPU: G45 Revision: B3
Device ID: 8086-2A43 Subvendor: Lenovo (17AA)
Second: 
GPU: G45 Revision: B3
Device ID: 8086-2A42 Subvendor: Lenovo (17AA)

The only difference is that at the second (first doesn't show anything), I see bios version:
1989 PC 14.34 02/10/2010 02:07:49
Also, driver is different:
First:
**8.641.1.1000 / Win 7 64**

Second:
**igdumd64 8.641.1.1000 / Win7 64**

(I know, I know tl;dr. But as a side-note: When I switch to ATI only (discrete), I can perfectly update the driver to 10.8 and it all works perfect. However, ATI is just a monster compared to the Intel's consumption. That's why I'd like to use the Intel card.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling all the graphics drivers you have installed and then use ThinkVantage System Update to get the latest ones from Lenovo.

Comment: That's another story. After I switch to Intel, it'll tell me there is no packages for my system. WHILE with ATI, it offers me about 4 or 5 packages to install... quite funny (or not ? :/)

Comment: Try installing the graphics driver updates that you see while switched to ATi.  They may enable and make the system aware of the switchability of the graphics.  Stick with the System Update suggested drivers only for this reason.

Comment: But yeah.. I disabled the switchability and I don't want it. Seems like I'll just have to use the ATI card.

Comment: @Shiki:  Well, I was answering your question.  If you want to use the Intel graphics for extended battery life, you should enable it.

Comment: Well..but the lack of a correct driver is something I can't tolerate. Seems like I'll have to fetch an Amazon Kindle or something. :/